# On SO: Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None”

Tags: bug, cookies

It appears that Stack Overflow still has a problem as reported in Firefox's developer tools:

> Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

This seems to be a problem with an easy solution:

[How to set "secure" attribute of the cookies used by Google Analytics Global Site Tag (gtag.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569419/how-to-set-secure-attribute-of-the-cookies-used-by-google-analytics-global-sit)

Presumably that cookie has a financial impact on Stack Overflow somewhere along the line, so there could be an incentive to fix the issue.

Don't we *expect* SO to be an exemplar of an error-free website? And who doesn't like their own website to present nothing in the developer tools console???

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's quite a bit of [controversy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377822/stop-tracking-users-without-their-consent) regarding this particular cookie being set as a strictly necessary cookie, which is probably why people disagree with fixing this.

Comment: That said, this change will effectively nullify the 25k+ privilege for users to see site analytics, as that uses Google Analytics to show the data.

Comment: I mean, isn't the worst that can happen that SE's ability to track their users without permission is reduced? Big deal, kill it with fire instead

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine *Someone* has to pay to keep the blinkenlights going. I agree that being sneaky is not nice. But maybe they could be sneaky without technical errors.

Answer (score 5):

Let this be the only time I say this unironically.

## k

I have a lot of ad-blockers on my browsers so I'm not dramatically impacted by this, but of all of the cookies to suddenly be broken in Firefox, it couldn't have happened to a better one.